# Uncaught PDOException when using åäö

Tags: sql-server, pdo, utf-8, odbc

I use to use sqlsrv_connect but changed it to PDO.
Now i got this syntax error when using åäö.

When i used sqlsrv_connect i could do this:

```
SELECT Order, [Benämning], [Vår ref] FROM table
```

and it worked.

Now i'm trying to figure out how to do it with PDO.
So i tried:

```
SELECT Order, [Benämning], Antal FROM table
```

And got this error:

> Operand type clash: text is incompatible with float

And i tried:

```
SELECT Order, Benämning, Antal FROM table
```

And i got error:

> Incorrect syntax near '�'.

In the connection i added utf8:

```
$sql = new PDO("odbc:Driver=$driver;server=$serverName,$port;Database=$database;ConnectionPooling=0", $uid, $pwd,
        array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
        )
    );
```

Now, when pasting this i can se: PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_I... I'm connecting to SQL.. not MYSQL. Can this be the problem?

If i remove the "Benämning" column and just select columns without åäö or space the select works just fine.

**UPDATE**

I got åäö to work with sqlsrv instead of odbc.

Comment: SQL is a _language_. Do you perhaps mean you're connecting to SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh Yes of corse. MSSQL Server

Comment: Use the same driver with PDO: `$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database", $uid, $pwd);`.

Comment: @Zhorov Error connecting to SQL Server: Time out

Comment: @BjörnC, how do you connect to SQL Server with `sqlsrv-connect()`? You need to use the same options with the `PDO` version of the driver.

Comment: @Zhorov i had to put in "Driver" to get it to work: $sql = new PDO("sqlsrv:Driver=$driver;server=$server,$port;Database=$database;ConnectionPooling=0", $uid, $pwd,

Comment: I got "åäö" to work now with sqlsrv. How can i handle space "Vår ref" ?

Comment: @BjörnC, use `SELECT [Vår ref], ...`

Comment: @Zhorov perfect. You can use your comments to create an answear to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to use the same driver (PHP Driver for SQL Server) and the same connection options when you create the `PDO` instance.

```
<?php

...

try
   $sql = new PDO("sqlsrv:Driver=$driver;server=$server,$port;Database=$database", $uid, $pwd);
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   ... 
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    ...
}

try {
    $sql = "SELECT [Vår ref], ... FROM ...";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    ...
}

?>
```

Some additional notes:

- You need to quote the column name (`[Vår ref]`) to make the string literal a valid SQL Server identifier.
- Use driver specific PDO connection [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/pdo-setattribute?view=sql-server-ver16) (`PDO::SQLSRV_xxx`) to add driver specific features. The `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` option is useful if you connect to MySQL instance.